# Android alarm manager, send intent after 15 mins

Tags: java, android, alarm

I'm trying to send intent with the help of alarm manager after 15 mins.
But it doesn't work.

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (timeToReset * 1000);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, _peindingIntent);
```

But if timeToReset equals 60 seconds, it work's

Comment: Could you print the value of timeToReset when you make call with 15 minutes ? Also, which targetSdkVersion are you using ?

Comment: timeToReset  is 300 seconds

Comment: that is 5 minutes, not 15. Does that fact make any difference ? O_O

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work with 5 mins too, I don't know why :(

Comment: can you try with 18 ? there were some changes in API 19, although i doubt this will fix the issue. You seem to be using AlarmManager as intended. The only other issue could be value of time parameter.

Comment: What is your defintion of "does not work"? You get the alarm at incorrect time? Not at all? Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (60*1000*15);
```

Comment: Or `TimeUnit.MINUTES.`[`toMillis`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMillis(long))`(15)`

Comment: try this                                                                  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.MINUTE*15,pi);

Comment: alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.MINUTE*15,pi);